# What is the "tip" of the reed

Tags: oboe

What is the "tip" of an oboe reed?

Is the upper part of the hole of the reed or the bottom part?

[image]

Comment: Think 'tip of the tongue...'

Answer (score 8):

The tip of a reed usually refer to the front edge. For an oboe, that includes  both upper and lower parts of the reed. Here's a diagram:

[image]

Stolen from https://www.crookandstaple.com/pages/how-to-adjust-oboe-reeds